# Electron build decreases performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, biginteger, electron-builder

In my current side project my code is performing a large amount of very simple computation on large numbers.

- I'm using the library "big-integer@1.6.51" to handle the large number aspect.
- I'm using the library "electron@28.0.0" & "electron-builder@24.9.1" to bundle the final product
- I'm using "node:worker_threads" to run this code in a separate Thread

To simplify my loop is:

```
let t = // big number
let b = a // big number
while(t > 0) {
     b = b ^ (2^1024) MOD N
     t -= 1024
}
```

To monitor the performance, I've implemented a benchmark function that permits to get the velocity of this loop on my hardware (number of exponentiation per second)

- If I'm running the benchmark on nodeJS I got something around **400 kExp/s**
- If I'm running the benchmark in dev with Electron (started with "electron .") I got something around **800 kExp/s**
- If I'm running the benchmark in prod with Electron (bundled with electron-builder) I got something around **400 kExp/s**

Do you have an idea to explain why Electron is so fast in development mode ? I'm very curious about the reason which can explains such differences.

Comment: How are you doing the benchmarking? And how many times did you measure performance?

Comment: Hey, thanks for asking, in order to perform the benchmark I count the number or exponentiation done divided by the run time. All the benchmarks converges in about 10 to 15 seconds and I did multiple runs of 1 minutes, variations in the result are really minimal (2-5%)

Comment: Can you post _complete_ benchmarking code/instructions that someone could use to reproduce your results (and investigate/profile what's happening under the hood)?